# Manually add a migration?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I've been using Entity framework code first in a project and all the tables have been created /modified a while ago. Now I need to add an unique constraint to a table. I want to create a migration which will have the following row in the `Up()` method. And there is **no change on the model classes**.

```
CreateIndex("TableName", new[] { "Column1" }, true, "IX_UniqueKey");
```

And maybe the following row in the `Down()`

```
DropIndex("TableName", new [] { "Column1" });
```

Can I just manually create a file under the folder *Migrations*? And is there any mandatory file name convention?

How to create the `.Designer.cs` and `.resx` files? Or should I use `add-migration` with some parameters?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using add-migration is the way for this.
Just use `add-migration yourMigrationName` and it will automatically create all the files you need.

Then you just alter the Up() and Down() methods with the values that you need

Comment: But I don't have any change on the Model classes. Will `add-migration name` still generate the files with empty `Up()` and `Down()`?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 yes it will

Comment: is there any way except use `add-migration` ? Since I got an error said `The Entity Framework is not installed on project 'xxx'`.. I use EntityFramework 6.2.0 and NuGet Version 4.6.0

Comment: For anyone wondering, I can confirm that this will work for EF Core as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add a migration with the following template (belongs in your Migrations folder):

```
  /// <inheritdoc />
  [DbContext(typeof(YourDbContext))]
  [Migration("20230917114131_MyMigration")]
  public partial class MyMigration : Migration
  {
      /// <inheritdoc />
      protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
      {

      }

      /// <inheritdoc />
      protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
      {
          
      }
  }
```