# EF 6 + Asp.Net core creating a migration manually (in whole)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

Hi how do I create a migration manually in EF6 and asp.net core with the new VS projects format? The reason is that automatic migration still don't work after two years and seems that EF 6.3.0 is far from being completed, and I absolutely need to create a migration manually etc.

This answer partially answer:
[Manually add a migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447331/manually-add-a-migration)

Comment: Which of your requirements are missing? From the way the question is asked, it seems the link is providing the full answer.

Comment: nope, in the other a question there is a answer that tells to use the command "add-migration", but that command won't work in this scenario because of this error (yet to be resolved) : https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/231

Comment: AOProject error

Comment: What prevents you from using the EF Core which is the recommended way?

Comment: legacy library that I cannot change