# Entity Framework Migration with no model changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am wondering if it makes sense to create a migration for a scenario where there aren't necessarily *model changes*, but the enum property on a model has been changed. I'm using `.NET 4.6.2` and `Code-First Entity Framework`

I have the following EF-tracked log model:

```
[Table("Logs")]
public class Log
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public LogType Type { get; set; } 
}
```

The `LogType` enum currently has around 40 values, of which, 13 have become obsolete or deprecated. I am going through the process of removing references to the obsolete/deprecated enum values.

As such, the values of the `LogType` enum are being changed. For example, `LogType.ConnectionTimeout` used to have the value `16`, but now has the value `3`.

In my database (MSSQL), the `Type` column is stored as an int, and I have written SQL that deletes all entries with an obsolete/deprecated enum value, and I have also written SQL that updates the other enum values to match what their new values are (e.g. changing 16 to 3 using my previous example of `Type.ConnectionTimeout`).

My question is this: Is it a good practice to put that SQL in a migration that is able to be `Up()`'d and `Down()`'d? My other question is, is that even possible? Or does there need to be actual model changes to create a migration? I'd like to be able to have this SQL tracked and stored in version control, as well as the ability to `Up()` and `Down()` it in the future if need be.

Thanks, and apologies in advance if this is a duplicate -- I wasn't able to find a similar question through my searches.

Comment: You can certainly [add an empty migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447331/manually-add-a-migration)

Comment: @stuartd thanks, this is what I need